# Please solve A problem of Green's Theorm

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

The question is $$\oint_{(4x^2+y^2=1)}\left(-\frac{(x^2y)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\,dx+\frac{x^3}{(x^2+y^2 )^2}\,dy\right)$$

I solved that

$$P=-\frac{(x^2y)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\qquad Q=\frac{x^3}{(x^2+y^2 )^2}$$

$$\begin{align}\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}&=\frac{(3x^2 (x^2+y^2 )^2- 4x^4 (x^2+y^2 ))}{(x^2+y^2 )^4}\\ 
&=\frac{(x^2 (x^2+y^2 )(3y^2-x^2 ))}{(x^2+y^2 )^2}\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}&=\frac{(-x^2 (x^2+y^2 )^2+4x^2 y^2 (x^2+y^2 ))}{(x^2+y^2 )^2}\\
&=\frac{(x^2 (x^2+y^2 )(3y^2-x^2 ))}{(x^2+y^2 )^2}\end{align}$$

So $$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}$$

Therefore $$\iint_D\left(\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}\right)\,dA=\iint_D0\,dA=0$$

$$\oint_{(4x^2+y^2=1)}\left(-\frac{(x^2y)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\,dx+\frac{x^3}{(x^2+y^2 )^2}\,dy\right)=0$$

It's my solution.

But my professor told me it's not true because of $(0, 0)$.

I have no idea about that..

How can I solve it? Please help me;

Comment: Please write this in LaTeX formatting. Some of your symbols didn't render properly and it's very confusing to read this as is.

Comment: @Cameron Williams Thank you for edit. And I'm sorry that I don't know using LaTeX Formatting yet. As soon as possible, I learn about it.

Comment: I do not understand the question.  What does $$\oint_{4 x^2+y^2}$$ mean?

Comment: @RonGordon It means that integral at closed interval $4x^2+y^2$.

Comment: That makes no sense to me.  You should have a closed curve that is of the form $f(x,y)=c$; i.e., an equation.  You have an expression.

Comment: @RonGordon oh! I'm sorry;; I have a mistake; I need to modify   $4x^2+y^2=1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Green's Theorem does not apply, as the vector field has a singularity inside the curve. However, you *can* apply Green's Theorem to the region bounded by the ellipse and, say, the unit circle. So your integral equals the integral around the unit circle, which can be computed directly.

To be more clever, we note that the integral around the unit circle, $\displaystyle\oint_C -x^2y\,dx + x^3\,dy$ can itself be evaluated by Green's Theorem, obtaining $
\displaystyle\int\int_{\{x^2+y^2\le 1\}} 4x^2\,dA$. This, in turn, can be done easily in polar coordinates, and you should get the answer $\pi$.

Comment: I'm appreciate you!!! Thank you!!!